# Ruby On Rails gallery zip archive download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, carrierwave

I have a rails app that allows users to create galleries and then have people upload photos to the gallery. I was wondering what's the easiest most efficient way for users to download the gallery as a zip file with all containing pictures inside? The gallery can change anytime since users can upload pictures.

Tech wise, the app uses carrierwave and uploads the pictures to amazon S3 while being hosted on Heroku.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Dillon Raphael! Although you did describe your problem, it is difficult to help you without knowing what your code looks like. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check out [Rubyzip gem](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip). Also, as your galleries change often you should to generate zip archive on the fly, I guess.